# Installing XP via external Hard drive

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I'm having a few problems trying to install Windows XP via an external hard drive. I've formatted the hard drive to NTFS, pasted all the files from the XP CD to the Hard Drive and then tried to boot into after a restart, however, I keep getting BOOTMGR missing press ctrl + alt + del to restart.

Comment: This is very difficult to do without some serious tweaks. Why not install from the CD/DVD?  More info please.

Comment: @DaveM nah I doubt it needs serious tweaks. i've probably done it before

Comment: @DaveM Because I want to try and install it from the external hard drive. There is no problem with the CD.

Comment: You have to boot off the USB HDD. That means you make the USB HDD run DOS.  That's easy to do if you have a Floppy Drive, as you make a bootable floppy and you run the SYS F: or whatever your USB HDD is. Then make sure COMMAND.COM and IO.SYS and maybe MSDOS.SYS  are on there (one of those maybe msdos.sys is plain text and may not be necessary). Then you just boot off the USB HDD,  run SETUP.EXE on the CD.  Presumably you've got that far?

Comment: Ah,  your mistake was formatting the USB HDD within XP. That gave it the XP  Master Boot Record.  A DOS Floppy disk or DOS HDD, should not be formatted with XP's format.exe command.  In fact look at the MBR with Roadkil's sector editor and you'll see that.  So, what to do. You need to find some way to format your USB HDD. Perhaps You can format it within XP then use the SYS command on it which should fix it. You might have to format it as FAT32 actually. I always formatted from DOS from a boot floppy, then you have the right format command, that's much easier and was the normal way.

Comment: I formatted it within Windows 7 - will this make a different? It doesn't give me the option for just "FAT32" or "FAT" it gives me "exFAT"

Comment: @DaveM  I remember a really up to date guy around 2001-2002 saying Win XP came on floppy disks. Maybe it did before CD. It's definitely quite normal to install win xp from HDD. In fact it may be quicker. People did it with 98 all the time. With XP they probably continued, I probably did. But now with USB people often use USB

Comment: @KevinDodd yeah downloa roadkil's sector editor, and look at the first sector, you'll see it's not right. It should have words like IO.SYS in it if it's right.  You could download a virtual floppy drive then run an EXE from www.bootdisk.com and write a floppy. Then use that to Format your USB drive right. Then look at it in Roadkil's sector editor to check.   If you have a proper external floppy drive you don't need to do the virtual one. I think vfd.exe was what I used once vfd.exe http://vfd.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Another way, probably easier as i'm not sure how you'd run SYS F, even with a virtual floppy, as sys.com or sys.exe, may not run within windows. You can run HPUSBFW.EXE or maybe Rufus will do it too(rufus may be even better), and create a USB DOS Bootable. Make sure it has the SYS command and hope that it recognizes other USB devices. Then you could boot from it and run SYS F: on your drive or sys whatever:   on your drive.  You do it by nook or crook, I don't recall how so perhaps try different things to get that MBR right! To get SYS F: to run.

Comment: The way I used to do, is Boot off a DOS floppy disk.  And then your main hard drive is internal, so is going to be recognized. I'd then partition the main internal hard drive or have already partitioned it in Partition Magic. So I didn't use any USB drives. (as DOS doesn't normally see USB!).  So then i'd have prepared my internal hard drive so it's ready to install XP. I'd then boot the hard drive which went to DOS, then changed to the partition with XP installtion e.g. C:\>E: <ENTER> then CD i386 <ENTER> SETUP <ENTER>.

Comment: With the USB DOS bootable idea,  what I mean is you could perhaps boot off USB to DOS, and then run SETUP.EXE from the USB. So you copy the setup files to your USB stick.  I've never done it but it should work easily.  DOS easily recognizes the USB  you're booting from. And there are programs like HPUSBFW that make DOS bootable USB  s. In fact, maybe HPUSBFW or Rufus, will format your USB HDD as DOS, as maybe it's like a giant USB stick, maybe. Do report back after trying some of these ideas

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something but XP has an issue that it is loading drivers and files during install it drops the USB connection.  When the installer tries to read the source USB, it cannot find the drive.

Certainly it is possible to boot from a floppy or something and access an external drive but running setup from the drive has an issue.

I know there were some workarounds posted some time ago and here is one [Possible Fix](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/how-to-install-and-boot-windows-on-an-external-usb-hard-drive.116114/)

Windows 7 does not have this issue.